# What does it mean when Big Query shows this error message?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error, aggregates

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(customer_id) AS id_count,
    purchase_price,
    purchase_size
FROM 
    charjx-project-twenty-three.customer_data1.customer_purchase
WHERE
    purchase_size > 1
ORDER BY
    purchase_size
```

Error message is:

> SELECT list expression references column purchase_price which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:3]

I'm super new to SQL. So I'm learning the Ins and outs, especially with errors.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using aggregate function `COUNT`, other columns must be in the `GROUP BY` clause so that aggregate function can provide you the aggregated result based on the grouped columns.

You just need to include `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
WHERE
  purchase_size >1
GROUP BY
  purchase_price,
  purchase_size
ORDER BY
  purchase_size
```